# Cabal update now can't load any modules from "hidden packages"

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci

I've been working on a project and recently I did a `cabal update`.

I usually roll into `ghci` like:

```
$ ghci -package-db ~/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.7/package.db
```

After the update loading module in my project results in even the basic Haskell modules like `System.Random` or `MonadIO` fails with the following errors when trying to load my own module called `ProcessIO`:

```
ProcessIO.hs:50:1: error:
    Could not load module ‘Data.IORef.MonadIO’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘monadIO-0.11.1.0’.
    You can run ‘:set -package monadIO’ to expose it.
    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)
    Locations searched:
      Data/IORef/MonadIO.hs
      Data/IORef/MonadIO.lhs
      Data/IORef/MonadIO.hsig
      Data/IORef/MonadIO.lhsig
```

I checked that maybe the `.cabal` file `build-depends` versions might have been altered, but the cabal `package.db` directory contains all the right versions of the dependencies in the `.cabal` file. For example the error above complains abot `monadIO-0.11.1.0` being hidden however: in `package.db/` we see the right version exists:

```
monadIO-0.11.1.0-0aec75273f3fef94783e211a1933f8ac923485a963be3b6a61995d4a88dd1135.conf
```

I should say I haven't looked at the `package.db` files before because everything simple *worked* so there may be something telling about the `.conf` file name that signals something is wrong.

Either way, can't build anything and I need some help!

EDIT: posting my default environments file  `~/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.10.7/environments/default` in case it matters:

```
clear-package-db
global-package-db
package-db /home/surya/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.7/package.db
package-id ghc-8.10.7
package-id bytestring-0.10.12.0
...
```

(Let me know if I need to share more of it... or less)

Comment: So manually adding `-package monadIO`, `-package random`, etc. works and allows my to compile, but I'd lik to not have to do that every time and at least kind of understand what went wrong with my cabal project

Comment: Would you post your .cabal file and just in case try cleaning the build dir?